# Can GeoServer work with flat coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-systems, geoserver, srs, wkt, epsg

I have an application that displays different items on the custom map. The map has a coordinate system which is basically (X,Y) coordinates in centimeters where top-left corner has coordinates(0,0). All items are displayed relatively to this coordinate system.

I want to change the application to use the GeoServer to serve the map. GeoServer uses EPSG as SRS (which is not very clear for me at the moment). I don't really care about how my map relates to the world coordinates. What is the better way to show my items on the map served by the GeoServer with some EPSG defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here: http://geo-solutions.blogspot.it/2011/05/developers-corner-turning-geoserver.html

You'll need a recent version of GeoServer, EPSG:404000 can be used for vector data as well.